# jQuery hide and show effect seen at function end

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, hide

Consider the following code:

```
<div id="thediv" >hola</div>
<button id="resharper">button</button>
```

with javascript/jQuery:

```
$("button").on( 'click', function() {
    $("#thediv").show();
    alert('click');
});

$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#thediv").hide();
})
```

I want the behavior to first show the div tag and then display the alert "Click". Instead the behavior works in the opposite way. Alert text is first displayed followed by the button being visible. Am i missing something ?

Can i modify the code somehow to get the desired behavior where the div is first displayed and then alert text is flashed.

Comment: Is it the same with ajax calls? Instead of alert, if i have an ajax call, is the root cause the same ?

Comment: If you have set `async: false` on the AJAX call then it would be the same problem - but you should never, ever use `async: false` for that reason

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check that in [jQuery.show(options)](http://api.jquery.com/show/) allows you to pass a [PlainObject](http://api.jquery.com/Types/#PlainObject) options.

And than you can use `complete`: A function that is called once the animation on an element is complete.

Code:

```js
$("button").on( 'click', function() {
    $("#thediv").show({ 
      complete: function() {
        alert('click');
      } 
    });
});

$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#thediv").hide();
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="thediv" >hola</div>
<button id="resharper">button</button>
with javascript/jQuery:
```

Answer (score 0):

It's because the `alert()` blocks the UI thread from updating, and that thread has not yet had time to show the element in the DOM before you call the `alert()`.

Ideally you should use `console.log()` for debugging, however you can avoid this issue by putting the `alert()` in a `setTimeout()` with a very short delay.

```js
$("button").on( 'click', function() {
    $("#thediv").show();
    setTimeout(function() {
      alert('click');
    }, 10);
});
```

```css
#thediv { display: none; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="thediv" >hola</div>
<button id="resharper">button</button>
with javascript/jQuery:
```

Comment: Is it the same with ajax calls? Instead of alert, if i have an ajax call, is the root cause the same ?

Comment: If you have set `async: false` on the AJAX call then it would be the same problem - but you should never, ever use `async: false` for that reason

Comment: Instead of `setTimeout()` better to use the the [jQuery.show(options)](http://api.jquery.com/show/#show-options)

Comment: @YosvelQuintero I agree. Your answer is the best one here. I upvoted it

Comment: @YosvelQuintero 's solution does work. Thanks for the explanation, Rory.

Answer (score 0):

```js
$("button").on('click', function() {
  $("#thediv").show("slow", callback);
});

$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#thediv").hide();
})

function callback() {
  alert('click');
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="thediv">hola</div>
<button id="resharper">button</button>
```

1. Add parameter to `.show()`

Comment: While this works the logic is slightly different, as you're now animating the reveal. `show(0, callback)` would be closer